# How do I use harmony_async_iteration with jest?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I would like to test code in a node project that uses async iteration without using babel.

Based on https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2485, I tried running jest using `node --harmony_async_iteration ./node_modules/.bin/jest`. However, I still see syntax errors in my module where async iteration syntax is used. The node command line option was ineffective, as if jest spawned a new process for the test runner, without using `--harmony_async_iteration`.

My async iteration source file is parsed without error when loaded by node (without jest) using `--harmony_async_iteration`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel is an integral part of jest. It is not necessary to use babel to transpile your application for non-test use, but babel absolutely must be configured in order to allow async generators to work with jest.

Install the babel-plugin-transform-async-generator-functions:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-async-generator-functions
```

or

```
yarn add --dev babel-plugin-transform-async-generator-functions
```

Activate the plugin by creating a .babelrc file (or add to the file):

```
{ "plugins": ["transform-async-generator-functions"] }
```

Now your jest tests should work with async generators.